# How do I get the index of the element closest to an element in a list which will be manaully assigned

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

So I have a list

```py
stock = [5,6,8,4,8,3,6,4]
val = 5
```

I want to get the index of the element closest to the 1st occurrence of the val variable in the list. So what I want to get will be 4 with index 3. if val = 8 then I will get 6 with index 1, if val = 3, since its the lowest value, I will get -1 I have tried using this code.

```py
closest = min(range(len(stock)), key=lambda i: abs(stock[i]-val))
```

but it just returns back the index of val variable

Comment: I don't quite understand, can you explain it to me?

Comment: "the **greatest** element **closest** to ... " Which one is more important? For example with your list `stock` and `val=5`, should the resulting index be `1`, because `6` is closest, or `2` because `8` is the largest element?

Comment: it will check for the element that is closest to it, the closest element to it is 4 and the index of 4 is 3

Comment: Ah now I get it. The problem in your solution is, that 0 difference is included. But you want a difference of at least one, so look for the second smallest element.

Comment: Sounds good for codegolf: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: `stock.index(max((_ for _ in stock if _ < val)))`  returns your needed index and throws an error if lowest value is given..

Answer (score 1):

This involves a lot of iterations, but still one way to find what you need... Should be modified if negative values are also in the picture.

```
def one_expensive_way_to_find_what_you_need(list_, val):
   try:
      return list_.index(max((_ for _ in stock if _ < val)))
   except:
      return -1
```

Comment: your solution fails for 
```python 
list = [5,6,8,4,9,10,8,3,6,4]
val = 9
```
it selects 8 as the lowest number closest to 9, even though 8 is directly lower than 9, the answer is 4 as 4 is closest to 9

Comment: I see.. Originally the question was to find the largest element closest.. So kind of seemed weight age added to the "largest"

Answer (score 0):

As [Feodoran already pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62271713/how-do-i-get-the-index-of-the-element-closest-to-an-element-in-a-list-which-will/62272063#comment110133058_62271713), your solution does not handle closest *but less than `val`* part that you want, and also the `-1` edge-case. Hence it gives you index of the `val` variable, since that always has difference of `0` which will be returned by the `min`.

You need something like -

```py
INF = 10 ** 9
closest = min(
    range(len(stock)),
    key=lambda i: abs(stock[i] - val) if stock[i] < val else INF
)
if closest == 0 and stock[0] >= val:
    closest = -1
```

The `if` condition in the `lambda` takes care of the less than `val` part by assigning the difference to an arbitrarily high number, which in my case, I've taken as `10**9`. Depending on your use case, this could be kept higher. Also, the edge-case of `val` being `min(stock)` is handled by the last 2 lines, needed due to the solution approach you've taken.